# How to center a not centered png file inside a container in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, assets

Hello I have an app where I want to put the female image {**X/Y** image at the top is not part of the female pic, it's a separate widget} in the bottom center of the app. However, as I was using the image.asset the image is not centered. How to manually center the image without cropping the image itself?

Here is my code:

```
Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/XYicon1.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            height: 250,
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Here is my output and the not centered image itself (2nd pic)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Stack to fine tune the position of you widget:

```
Stack(
  children:[
    Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/XYicon1.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            height: 250,
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: -50,
      child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/2nd.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            height: 250,
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
          ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Is this the accepted answer? If so @Shammah, please mark it as such. :)